# Converting excel spreadsheet data into Salesforce Objects

Tags: excel

Say that I am currently storing data in an excel sheet. Along the y-axis, I am storing the names of doctors. Along the x-axis, I have months. So then each individual cell represents how many patients a doctor met with in that particular month.

What is the best strategy to covert this into Salesforce? I was considering making a doctorOffice object and then have a custom field for each pair of doctor and month. But this doesn't seem very elegant. I am a little new to Salesforce and storing data by objects, does anyone see a better way to do this? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

Reconstruct your excel into Columns with DoctorName and Individual months(January, February, ...December)- 12 different columns such that each column will show the number of  patients.

Now save the excel with 'yourfilename'.**csv** file extenison.

In salesforce, make sure you create fields to save DoctorName and separate fields like Patients in January, Patients in February..... Patients in December(or however you desire to name it).

Install data loader and login and do an insert option choose doctorOffice object from a list that will be displayed and select your file 'yourfilename'.**csv** saved file.

Choose manual mapping and map the salesforce fields with csv file and select Next and finish. It will ask you to save the success and error files so provide a destination for that.

This should upload your data into Salesforce.

Comment: So for how the spreadsheet is currently formatted, I would need to create a Salesforce field for each excel cell in my DoctorsOffice object?

Comment: You will need to create **DoctorName, Number of Patients in January, Number of Patients in February, ...........Number of Patients in December** fields.

Comment: Does this account for the fact that there are more than one doctor in a doctor's office? Since if Doctor Name is a field, how would you be able to enter more than one Doctor name?

Comment: Each Doctor have it as a separate record.

Comment: Example: Doctor X Record will have DoctorName as X and then patients in each months in separate fields.